# Questions regarding JSP & servlet & MongoDB Mlab

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets

I am new to MongoDB Mlab, which means not familiar with how to use it and how to connect it with a DAO file. And I encounter a technical issue on SERVLET. Firstly, I try to extract data from MongoDB mlab to get an email & password of a user for my login page. And I also capture the email & password entered by a user on login JSP page by using "request.getParameter("")" method. These two points work fine because I already tested them. More info about my issue is that when I try to extract email and password from MongoDB mlab, I store these two parameters into a user object, and store the user object into an ArrayList. Then return this Arraylist to the login Servlet. Using for-each loop to traversal this list. I put the codes below.

[When I try to enter an email and password on the login page, this is the result I encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FGIe.png)
how can I solve it

### FDao.java

```js
package Dao;

import static com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import model.Book;
import model.Staff;
import model.User;
import org.bson.Document;

public class FDao {

    public List<User> checkLogin() throws UnknownHostException {
        
        Iterator it = DB.getDB().getCollection("users").find().iterator();
        List<User> aUser = new ArrayList();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Document o = (Document) it.next();
            aUser.add(new User(o.getString("email"), o.getString("password")));
        }
        return aUser;
    }
    
}
```

### LoginServlet.java(I capture string email and string password from login JSP page)

```js
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public LoginServlet() {
        super();
    }
    FDao userDao = new FDao();

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("pass");
        List<User> users = new ArrayList();
        users = userDao.checkLogin();
        
        for (User user : users) {
            if (email.equals(user.getEmail()) && password.equals(user.getPassword()) ) {
                //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                //session.setAttribute("user", user); 
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp").include(request, response); //the problem looks like appeared in this line of code
                //out.println("Hello World");
            } else {
                //String message = "Your account does not exist in out database!";
                //request.setAttribute("message", message); //message is object
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp").include(request, response);//the problem looks like appeared in this line of code
                //out.println("Nothing");
            }
            break;
        }

        
    }
}
```